# How do i get the URL from the caller of a HTTP Request?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Let's say that i have a navbar with a search bar, and it appears on every single page, so when the user click on the search button, it could happend 2 things:

1. Refresh the page if the **input is empty**
2. Redirect to a `SearchResult.cshtml` and show the results...

So the controller and action who handle the `HTTP POST Request` are `Search - SearchResult` respectively. I want to get the URL from the caller because the action method will need it to decide what page should redirect it. 
**PD**: I'm using ASP.NET CORE MVC 3.1

Comment: why not include the 'referrer url' as part of the form payload? Or as a GET parameter?

Comment: I'm a beginner on ASP.NET Core so i don't know what you're talking about. I would appreciate if you provide more details about it.

Comment: If the search input is inside a form add a hidden input with the current uri in it. When the user submits the search, not only will their current query be passed but also the url. Your `SearchResult` action should already have a model, you would just need to add the new value to it.

Comment: I see, so how do i get the url so i can assigned to hidden input, because i have the navbar inside a `_Layout.cshtml` file , so it's not like i can do it manually.

Comment: You can use the current `Context` in order to retrieve the request values. You only need the path/query. If you look at [GetEncodedPathAndQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.getencodedpathandquery?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_Extensions_UriHelper_GetEncodedPathAndQuery_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_) it should do the work for you. You will need to add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions nuget package to use it.

Comment: You might want to add the return url to the query string because forms arn't very good for state. Imagine if the user refreshes the page, the url in the form will be gone. But the method should remain the same. Instead of adding the URL to the hidden input, add it as a route value to the form when creating the action url. You should try both methods and see what works best for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is submit the current path/query along with your query.

You could accomplish that by having your search form be something like this.

```
<form asp-controller="Search" method="get">
  <input name="q" value="@Context.Request.Query["q"]" />
  <input name="r" type="hidden" value="@Context.Request.GetEncodedPathAndQuery()" placeholder="Search the thing" />
</form>
```

Notice im using a get method here. This is to keep the search state in the browser but you can manage that however you need too. Im also using [GetEncodedPathAndQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.getencodedpathandquery?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_Extensions_UriHelper_GetEncodedPathAndQuery_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_) which will need to be installed, but again the important part is to maintain the path/query(and more if this will be cross domain).

My controller will then look something like this.

```
[Route("/search")]
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(
        [Bind(Prefix = "q")] string query,
        [Bind(Prefix = "r")] string referrer)
    {
        IActionResult result = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
        {
            result = this.Redirect(referrer);
        }
        else
        {
            result = this.View(); // do search and return view.
        }

        return result ?? this.Redirect("/");
    }
}
```

This can obviously be adjusted in anyway you need. The main thing is accepting the two values from the request and handling them properly. You might also want to validate that the `referrer` is an actual url since the redirect action will throw if its not.

Answer (score 1):

In the Layout page, you could add a hidden field to store the current page URL, then, when click the Search button, in the SearchResult action, you could get the previous URL from the hidden field. Code as below:

_Layout.cshtml page,

```
    <div class="search">
        @{
            //get current url
            Uri currenturl = new Uri(String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}", Context.Request.Scheme, Context.Request.Host, Context.Request.Path, Context.Request.QueryString));  
        }

        <form asp-controller="Search" asp-action="SearchResult">
            <input class="text-body" type="text" value="" name="search" />
            <input name="returnurl" type="hidden" value="@currenturl" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Search" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Code in the SearchResult action:

```
    public IActionResult SearchResult()
    { 
        //get the returned url
        var returnurl = HttpContext.Request.Form["returnurl"].ToString(); 
        //do something
        return Redirect(returnurl);
    }
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]